# Why smartscreen only prompt sometimes when I download from different platform?

Tags: windows-10, prompt, smartscreen

I have been trying to figure out the reason behind smartscreen and I have read from microsoft's documentation (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/what-is-smartscreen-and-how-can-it-help-protect-me-1c9a874a-6826-be5e-45b1-67fa445a74c8) that smartscreen will appear when a downloaded file is from an untrusted web (that is not in the trusted list of microsoft) or when a downloaded file contains malicious software that has been reported to microsoft. I found out that if I download an .exe that was send through skype app, the smartscreen doesnt prompt but it does prompt when I download the .exe from skype web. However, when I download it from both Whatsapp app and web, the smartscreen was sure to prompt. So, I'm actually wondering what is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It basically flags all .exe files after checking the source (e.g. if source is Adobe, it lets it go). If the app has been sent through the Skype app, the system assumes the file would have been checked on the system that sent it and thus flags it safe.

Comment: But how is it different for Whatsapp? .exe downloaded from both whatsapp app and web has smartscreen.

Comment: Skype is Microsoft's service, so they impose some kind of pre-checks on the files before they are sent. WhatsApp is considered as a purely 3rd party thing for Microsoft.

Comment: Okay, I understand that but isn't Skype web a trusted site too? Because smartscreen was prompt when I downloaded the .exe from skype web

Comment: Yes, you're right to question that, in apps, you have full control as to what type of file to check before sending, after receiving, web is a completely differnent scene in some regards, so as of now they think it's mandatory to put checks of anything downloaded from the web version. It's purely their doing, how to think and implement.

Comment: In apps, you can't possiblty corrupt a file by any attack, the attacks are highly popular in the web scene making them more vulnerable. In the end, it's purely down to them.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing. However, I just tried going through Microsoft Team, both web and app but both also have smartscreen prompt. So I'm getting a little confuse of the situation.

Comment: There can be exceptions of course, what Microsoft are doing is not made public, so we can just make deductions